# How to predict in advance that a smart meter is failing?

Tags: outliers, unsupervised-learning

I have an electricity consumption data set collected by smart meters over a year and a half for every hour. The objective is to predict whether the meter could fail earlier than it actually fails.I have three columns CUSTOMER_ID, DATE/TIME-STAMP, CONSUMPTION. Meter reading degradation could point out that failure is about to happen, is there any way to detect this by using any algorithm? possibly any outliers or anomaly detection algorithm?

Comment: It could be helpful to link this to your own older, related [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140786/which-method-to-use-for-load-forecasting).

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by reading degradation.

Comment: @kasterma degradation in the sense the smart meter might start generating anomalous data before it actually breaks down. I need to know which algorithms to try out to detect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any idea of what is characteristic to a meter that is about to fail? Perhaps it stops working for a while and does so every now and then with increasing frequency? Then you would see periods of zero consumption in the data. If that happens when the consumption is normally high (in light of historical data), that could be an indication of meter failure. Or perhaps it shows unusually high values that are very unlikely or even technically impossible? You should be able to see that relatively easily (compare with historical peaks and/or technical upper limit).

The general idea would be to estimate some characteristics of the historical data (mean, variance, autocorrelations at different lags etc.) and see how the new data fits in, i.e. whether it has similar characteristics or not. The similarity could be quantified if you estimated some confidence bounds for the historical characteristics. You could use rolling windows over the historical data and collect the historical characteristics across all of them. Then you would have "clouds" of values and would be able to see the new value in the context of the "cloud". If the new value is close to the edge of the "cloud" or beyond it, it is an indication that something has changed, perhaps the meter went crazy.

If your data has a decent signal-to-noise ratio, you could try modelling your data. Again, use rolling windows to estimate a model, then predict a few points into the future. This way you will collect a set of predictions and the corresponding realized values (while still in the historical sample). You will see how well your model predicts in terms of, say, root mean squared error (RMSE), mean absolute percentage error (MAPE), mean absolute scaled error (MASE) etc. Then make a forecast from the last observed window of data. When new data comes in, you could see how well they accord with the forecast. If the forecast is much more off than typical in the light of historical data, you have a reason to suspect that either the meter is going nuts or the electricity consumption behaviour has changed.

Comment: First of all, Richard i would like to thank you for going through my query and responding, the answer has thrown light to further research. well I assumed that a meter would fail if it starts generating values that is not in sync with the user's usage pattern, so what i thought was to forecast the load and check for prediction errors, which is also what you stated. The problem now is that what algorithm? time series or Neural networks or SVM to use for load forecast.....will continue in next comment(Stack exchange doesnt allow me to type infinite characters ;) )

Comment: After going through few research papers, it seems several factors like weather,month,day of week, holidays,time of day all have effect on electricity consumption. Since i dont have any data related to weather but having all data related to rest mentioned above, i want to know which algorithm will be good to use and will have less MAPE. ....thanks in advance

Comment: I do not have experience with electricity load forecasting but I know there is a large literature out there. But perhaps most of it is not about individual users, so maybe it is irrelevant. Anyhow, [here](https://www.otexts.org/book/elf) is a whole free online textbook about electricity load forecasting. Maybe you will get some good ideas from there. With regards to different algorithms, the obvious (but also perhaps the most tedious) way is just to try out different methods on historical data and pick the one that performs best (to prevent overfitting, use training and validation).

Comment: I doubt you would be able to pick the best method without trying the candidate methods out on the historical data...

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard....i will try implementing all the algorithms....is there any other way to reach you, i might have doubts in working with time series in R.

Comment: I suggest you keep using Cross Validated and Stack Overflow instead of relying on me only for R help. I normally follow Cross Validated quite frequently, so perhaps I will notice your new question. Good luck!

Comment: @user3146895 I think you should be able to get the information related to weather from the general usage pattern (if it gets warm and ACs use more electricity, this is similar for most users).  This depends of course on how geographically disperse your users are (or if you can get geographic info on your users).

Comment: @katerma unfortunately all those datas are unavailable, we simply need to make predictions based on this.

Comment: @RichardHardy i have posted a new question about time series representation in R pls go through and any help is appreciated.